# Apple Keychain content is encrypted or encoded

Tags: keychain

Normally, it should show the account and the name in plain text. Then, if we click on 'Show Password,' it will display the password in plain text. However, currently, everything is encrypted or encoded.

This is not the base64 encoding, though. Any reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Which application created this Keychain entry? Are the Account and Password the same value?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure about that. I thought I already saved this via mobile or Safari Web browser automatically saved it.

Answer (score 2):

## Application Specific

This appears to be application specific behaviour. The [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) Application Programmer Interface (API) expects to handle the encryption and encoding of the credentials.

It is notable that the Account and Password entries appear to be identical. This is unusual.

Thus it appears the application writing the credentials is not using Keychain Services as originally intended.

If these credentials are stored within a `.keychain` file, you could use [Keysafe](https://miln.eu/keysafe/) to examine the contents.